# Overflow in Swiper

Tags: css, swiper.js

I'm using vertical full screen `Swiper` and ran into a problem. Due to content overflow for slide, I set `flex-wrap: wrap` and `overflow: scroll` so that this content can be viewed. But when I try to scroll the contents of the slide, the swipe scroll to the next one works at the same time. How to disable switching to the next slide until the previous one has scrolled completely?

**MainSlider.js**

```
<Swiper
        className={styles.swiper}
        direction={"vertical"}
        slidesPerView={"auto"}
        spaceBetween={0}
        mousewheel={true}
        speed={700}
        touchReleaseOnEdges={true}
        threshold={20}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
        }}
      >
        <SwiperSlide className={styles.slide}>
          <SectionOne/>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide className={styles.slide}>
          <AnswersTwo/>
        </SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
```

**MainSlider.module.scss**

```
.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slide {
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
```

Added a link to a similar example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-mousewheel-control-react-forked-c97l1q

Please note that if you display the code in full screen and then turn on the mobile version, the mouse wheel will work, but scrolling inside the container will also work, but with swipe you will not be able to flip the slide until you reload the page. After that, swipe will work, but there will be a problem that I wrote about at the very beginning. The woman needs to solve them both

Comment: Can you recreate your project in a [Codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io) and paste its link?

Comment: @yousoumar Added a link to a similar example